# How to send email verification code to user email in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to send email verification code to user's email using firebase authentication. I am using *(sendEmailVerification)* method but firebase sends a verification link to user's email. Is it possible to send verification code to user's email if yes then how it can be done?

I am using Angular 4 and for firebase angularfire2

Thanks.

Comment: As far as you are using firebase authentication you will be get template for Email verification. So all you need to perform is to change the Template given under authentication and then add Verification code in that.

Comment: There is no option to add Verification code in template. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 7):

If don´t want to use the solution provided by firebase, you have to handle all the process yourself and then update the user `emailVerified` data to `true`.

The basic 3 steps are:
1. send an email to the user with "whatever code" you want
2. in your logic, validate the "code" typed by the user
3. [use Firebase Admin SDK to update the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) *(you can only update this user property using the Admin SDK)*

Step 3 example, using NodeJS

```js
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {emailVerified:true})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
      console.log("update success", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Error updating user", err);
  });
```

Comment: Can you write steps 1 and 2 too?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth now supports the ability to pass state/continue URL in the email verification flow: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions (web and iOS, with Android on the way). The codes are pretty long unlike the 6 digit SMS codes. So copying the code, especially if you open the email on a different device is not feasible.