# How to send email with expirable code (token) from Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am doing an app that requires to send a verification code to the user before doing certain action. For example, for the user to login in the app, it is required to put the email, password (I used Firebase auth for this) and one code (the code could be a pin of 4 digits) that is sended to the user email. The token code is also needed when the user is going to perform a transaction (the app is a kind of basic bank).

I have search for how to doing this, but the articles I have found so far are not usefull. I will link the page of what I have found and why I think it is not usefull for me: 
 - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?hl=en-419
Not usefull because this tokens are use for authenticate an user as far as I understand, and not for send them for email.
 - [How to send email verification code to user email in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811741/how-to-send-email-verification-code-to-user-email-in-firebase)
Here, the code is needed just for verify the user email.

I have read a little about Firebase Cloud Functions, and this may help: there are examples sending welcome email to users; but the problem is that I need to send an email containing a kind of token (4 digits pin, again) that *expires passed X minutes after sended*.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle this is

- when the token is issued, save it in the database along with the current time
- when a token is received, load it from the database and check that `time of issue + expiration time > current time`

In other words, expiration is not a feature of the token itself, but a characteristic of how it is processed.